# Need recursive algorithm to search all of a BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Trying to come up with an algorithm to visit every node in the BST and compare each to find the largest int value, my BST is unbalance and sorted alphabetically but have int values with them and i need to find the largest int value in the tree.

my code is:

```
private Object Mode(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Object left = root.getElement();
    Object right = root.getElement();

    if (root.getLeftChild() != null) {

        Object leftEle = root.getLeftChild().getElement();

        if (left.data < leftEle.data) {
            left = Mode(root.getLeftChild());

        }
    }

    if (root.getRightChild() != null) {

        Object rightEle = root.getRightChild().getElement();

        if (right.data < rightEle.data) {
            right = Mode(root.getRightChild());

        }
    }

    if(left.data > right.data){
        return left;
    }

    return right;`

}
```

i know the comparisons happen when the method calls are popped back off the stack but i'm not sure if i end up actually checking all nodes

Comment: If you can put some (formatted) code in your description, folks here might be better able to help you with your syntax trouble. Your psuedo-code is pretty much accurate & does use recursion properly.

Comment: @MileHigh can you please elaborate this
`my BST is unbalance and sorted alphabetically but have int values with them`. What is the sorting order among an integer value and character?

Answer (score 0):

As your BST is not sorted by data then you need to traverse each and every node and compare between them. Remove those check `right.data < rightEle.data` & `left.data < leftEle.data`, it will limit the search space. I didn't compile you code yet. It should look like this:

```
private Object Mode(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Object left = root.getElement();
    Object right = root.getElement();

    if (root.getLeftChild() != null) {

        Object leftEle = root.getLeftChild().getElement();        
        left = Mode(root.getLeftChild());    
    }

    if (root.getRightChild() != null) {    
        Object rightEle = root.getRightChild().getElement();
        right = Mode(root.getRightChild());
    }
    if(left != null ){
        if(right != null)
            if(left.data < right.data
                return right;
        return left;

    }

    return right;


}
```